# Scoring Formula

Tags: math, formula

Let's say `A` can take on following values `[0,1,...,100]`. `W` (or weight) can take on `[0.0,0.1,...,1.0]`. What is a good scoring formula for weighting both `A` and `W` such that the score, `S`, is:

```
"good" when A and W are high
decent/"doesn't matter" when A is high and W is low
decent/"doesn't matter" when A and W are low
"bad" when A is low and W is high
```

Note: It's often the case that A is 0 and W is low. I want to prevent `X` from having a bad score then.

Comment: Is this homework?  Can you define "high" and "low"?  Isn't this a math question, rather than a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

A method that will give you +1 when A=100 and B=1 are high, -1 when A=0 and B=1 and 0 when B=0 with a bilinear blend between these values is:

```
a = 2*(A/100)-1
b = B

score = b * a
```

You'll need to rescale/threshold the output to get what you want. If you actually want the textual values as your return then you'll need something like this added to the end.

```
if(score<-0.5) return "bad"
if(score>0.5) return "good"
return "decent/doesn't matter"
```